# React click is not detected

Tags: reactjs

I have a component where I want to listen to its click event by using an onClick attribute. Simple stuff. However, when I click the component the click event doesn't fire.

My component structure is as follows (I use styled-components, but that should not be related):

```
// this comes from my UI library

const Icon = styled.div`
  /* some css properties */ 
`

const Search = () => (
  <Icon>
    /* this is an svg imported from the react-icons library */
    <MdSearch />
  </Icon>
)


// this is where I use the stuff from my UI library

class SomeComponent extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    // do something
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        /* some other stuff */
        <Search onClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The click is only detected when I spread the props down in the Search component, like this:

```
const Search = (props) => (
  <Icon {...props}>
    /* this is an svg imported from the react-icons library */
    <MdSearch />
  </Icon>
)
```

However, I am totally confused by this behaviour. Why can I not just make any component directly clickable? But instead have to manually pass the onClick prop down to the next DOM element? If that's just how it is, is there a more elegant solution than spreading the props? Because that would kind of mess up my whole UI library... :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `{...props}` is required in this way:

```
<Icon {...props}>
    /* this is an svg imported from the react-icons library */
    <MdSearch />
</Icon>
```

so that the props you are passing in to `Search` (ie the `onClick={this.handleClick}`) actually get passed and attached to, a component inside of the (functional) component. Without the `...props`, those props are passed in but are then not actually "attached" to anything, or used in anyway.

To not use the spread operator as shown above is roughly equivalent to creating a the following function:

```
foo(x) { return 1 }
```

and wondering why different values for `x` don't affect the behaviour/result of `foo`.

Hope that clarifies and helps :-)